# Working on audio effects for multiple clips at once

Tags: audio, davinci-resolve

My problem is that I have many clips with audio and I need to remove, modify and apply audio effects to all of them at once.

Initially, I added an audio effect to a long clip and then I split it in many smaller clips. My problem is that now I want to remove all audio effects so I can start again from scratch. I can select multiple audios but the options available to be changed at once are only the standard options (volume, etc), not the effects, even though the selected audios have the same effects applied.

I can use the Edit Index to select Audio tracks and then Audio with effects. But apparently this only identifies the offensive tracks, I can't select them all at once:

[image]

I have checked Resolve manual and I couldn't find anything.

**How can I remove the applied effects from the multiple tracks at once?**

After that, I will need to apply some effects to multiple tracks at once, but I believe this can be done by selecting all tracks and dragging and dropping the effect on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can lasso them on the timeline, right-click and choose "remove attributes..."  Then, make sure "plugins" is checked, and click "apply."

> After that, I will need to apply some effects to multiple tracks at once, but I believe this can be done by selecting all tracks and dragging and dropping the effect on them.

Yes, you can do that.  You can also apply effects to a whole track, which often saves a lot of mouse clicks, and helps you stay consistent.  There's a row of tiny plus signs on the mixer channel strips labeled "effects" where you go to do that.  It's also possible to group multiple tracks together, send that through a submix, and apply effects to the whole group at once.  So you could affect dialogue uniformly, for instance.

Comment: That was very helpful. Additionally, do you know if there is a way to select the tracks via the "Edit Index" as in the image of the question instead of using the "lasso"?

Comment: I don't think you can select multiple things via the edit index, but you can select one thing at a time if you have "selection follows playhead" turned on in the timeline menu.  That's something I use a lot, so I map a shortcut to it.  Then, with the edit index filtered the way you want it, you can step through with the up and down arrow keys.   You could work out a sequence of hot keys and use 3rd party macro software, which is always helpful for the inevitable edge cases.  Black Magic are very responsive to feature requests, though.  They implemented my last one in under a month.